# nexus with network shared drive as a source for product distribution website

Tags: nexus

Currently I have a network shared drive with some apache based authentication. This hosts product installers/webpages and such. Previously build tool (i.e. CI) would copy files there. This is fine, but the drive needs to be mounted on each build machine and the the path is not cross platform.

I recently put a nexus repository manager. I was wondering could I use the network shared drive as a repo and push all build artifacts there (e.g. .exe and such). This way would both nexus and apache would use the same folders. Then I could upload build artifacts anywhere and the path would be cross platform. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that you are looking for:

[How to configure Nexus work directory](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/30145206-Can-I-override-Nexus-configuration-properties-with-environment-variables-)

What you propably need to do is mount that drive in your system and modify configuration explained below:

Nexus will pull in some configuration data from environment variables. If these are defined they will override the values in "`$NEXUS_HOME/conf/nexus.properties`". For Nexus 2.x the following environment variables can be defined:

```
NEXUS_WORK
```

The location of the nexus work directory, where nexus stores all of its configurations and repository contents.
Defaults to `$(basedir)/../sonatype-work/nexus` - **This is the place where all snapshots and release libraries can be found** and the place that you can configure your network shared drive.

```
NEXUS_APPLICATION_HOST
```

The host/address(es) that the Nexus server will be listening on
Defaults to `0.0.0.0`, which means that Nexus will listen on all network interfaces

```
NEXUS_APPLICATION_PORT
```

The port that Nexus will be listening on
Defaults to `8081`

```
NEXUS_CONTEXT_PATH
```

The context path that the Nexus application will be served on
Defaults to `/nexus`
Caution: Generally we suggest avoiding using environment variables to configure Nexus if at all possible.

Caution: In older versions of Nexus these environment variables began with "PLEXUS" instead of "NEXUS".  Use of "PLEXUS" environment variables is deprecated, and support for these will be removed in a future release.

Comment: Thanks. What I had in mind was to create one hosted repo next to current ones which do store locally, i.e. one "customer releases" repo, and only this would go to network share. I might try the override local storage location option which is present when creating new repo.

Comment: You need to see sonatype-work dictionaries structure to fit your needs. Propably you could do that and mount drive to specific folder in that structure.